# How to get the RSS feeds URL of Joomla articles

Tags: joomla, rss

I have a Joomla site http://www.digitalsolutionss.com/blog/11-blog/39-places-to-visit-in-delhi-india. How can I get the RSS feeds of my joomla articles. What will be URL to show all article feeds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Global **rss feed** options could be found under:

```
Content -> Article Manager -> Options -> Integration -> Show feed link
```

If you want to set up a feed from **specific categories**, you could create a menu item that include articles from these categories and enable feed link under:

```
Menus -> *Menu Name -> *Menu Item -> Integration -> Show Feed Link
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this option is enabled. Still I am not getting the URL.

Comment: Please switch to default template and check again (it may has been removed from your template).